# Get Azure uploaded blob file url

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm uploading a data stream to Azure Storage,

I would get the link to the blob file.

```
let insertFile = async function (blobName,stream){
    const containerName= 'texttospeechudio';
    try{
       await blobService.createContainerIfNotExists(containerName, {
    publicAccessLevel: 'blob'},(err,result, response) => {
        if(!err) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
    let resultstream = blobService.createWriteStreamToBlockBlob(containerName, blobName,(err,result, response)=>{
        console.log(res)
    });
    stream.pipe(resultstream);
    stream.on('error', function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
    stream.once('end', function (end) {
        console.log(end)
      //OK
    });
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

I added `createWriteStreamToBlockBlob` callback , but I'm not getting inside it.

I would find a way to get uploaded file url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no file URL returned in the response according to put-blob's [rest spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob).

And Azure storage's resource URL can be commonly composed with following pattern:

https://{**myaccount**}.blob.core.windows.net/{**mycontainer**}/{**myblob**}